# How to understand a wrapped python code without passing arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand these lines of python [codes](https://github.com/google/paxml/blob/66c1d2baa83f3f0e26be501b1ee7283d49c3b687/paxml/partitioning.py#L610-L648).

```
def _wrapped_partitioned_step(
        state, prng_key, inputs, unpadded_global_batch_size=None
    ):
    del unpadded_global_batch_size
    return partitioned_step_fn(state, prng_key, inputs)

return _wrapped_partitioned_step, None
```

Here it tries to return a wrapped function. But i am confused why it does not requires passing a value, for example, state, prng_key, inputs, etc.

Comment: The caller of `partition()` will call the function with arguments. This is just returning a closure.

Comment: `del unpadded_global_batch_size` does nothing useful; it simply removes the reference to whatever object gets bound to it at call time. It does *not* affect anything outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the function to the caller of the containing method (`partition()`), and it's called with arguments from there. The docstring of the `Partitioner` class shows how it's used:

```
  # Partition the step function.
  partitioned_step_fn, input_pspec = partitioner.partition(
      step_fn, inputs_shape_dtype, is_eval)

  # Split and preprocess the prng key.
  prng_key, train_key = jax.random.split(root_prng_key)
  train_key = partitioner.preprocess_prng_key(train_key)

  # Get the inputs, preprocess and use it to run the partitioned function.
  inputs = train_input_pipeline.get_next_padded()
  inputs = partitioner.preprocess_inputs(
      train_input_pipeline, inputs, input_pspec)
  partitioned_step_fn(
      train_state, train_key, inputs, unpadded_global_batch_size)
```

`partitioned_step_function` is the function returned by the code you posted, and arguments are passed with

```
partitioned_step_fn(train_state, train_key, inputs, unpadded_global_batch_size)
```